# How to proof by induction this composite relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let R be a relation of set X and R°= Ix (identity relation of the set X), R¹= R and when n>=2 then Rⁿ+¹ = Rⁿo R.

How to proof by induction regarding the number m:
Rⁿ o Rᵐ =  Rⁿ+ᵐ, when m=1,2,3...

Answer (score 0):

Start with your base case, $m=1$ and prove it works. The assume you *know* it works for $m $ and prove that if that is the case, it *must* also work for $m+1$.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that the operation $\circ$ is associative. That is, given binary relations $A,B,C$ we have $(A\circ B)\circ C=A\circ (B\circ C)$.

To see why the operation is associative, notice that:
\begin{align*}
(x,y)\in (A\circ B)\circ C &\Leftrightarrow \text{There is $z$ such that $(x,z)\in (A\circ B)$ and $(z,y)\in C$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \text{There are $z,z'$ such that $(x,z')\in A$, $(z',z)\in B$ and $(z,y)\in C$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \text{There is $z'$ such that $(x,z')\in A$ and $(z',y)\in C$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow (x,y)\in A\circ (B\circ C)
\end{align*}

Now, se want to proof by induction on $m\geq 1$ that $R^n\circ R^m=R^{n+m}$.

By definition that $R^{n+1}:=R^n\circ R=R^n\circ R^1$, so the result holds for $m=1$.

Suppose as the induction hypothesis that $R^{n+m}=R^{n}\circ R^m$. Again by the definition, we have that

\begin{align*}
R^{n+(m+1)}&=R^{(n+m)+1}=R^{(n+m)}\circ R &\\
&=(R^n\circ R^m)\circ R &\\
&=R^n\circ (R^m\circ R) &\text{(by associativity of $\circ$)}\\
&=R^n\circ R^{m+1},
\end{align*}
as we desired.